# Search with grep discarding hyphen at the end

Tags: file, unix, search, select, grep

I want to select lines in a file that start with some pattern and DON'T end with an hyphen ("-")

I'm currently trying:

```
grep -v ".-" file | grep "^String"
```

It mostly works fine, but with the little exception that it "discards" any line that has any hyphen at any part, not only at the end, so, if i have a line with only the ending hyphen, it's fine, but if by chance, the line has another hyphen in the middle, it also discards it, even if it doesn't have one at the end.

¿How can i set it to discard ONLY the lines with an hyphen at the end? I'm sure it's a little problem in the syntaxis, so, any help is welcome :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only the end, you can use `$` to match the end of the line.

```
grep -v "\-$" file
```

Comment: Also tried that, doesn't work because the hyphen is a special character, tried adding -e and the same result =/

Comment: @user2266881 Try escaping it.

Comment: @user2266881 You shouldn't have to escape it, it works for me.  How are you running it?

Comment: Ahhhh, sorry guys, im a stupid... the problem was in the input file... it was adding an space after the hyphen, so, doing the same, but now with "- " instead of "-", everything worked :)

Comment: This answer might be useful too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: @squiguy: Why did you remove the backslash escape of the hyphen? It doesn't work for me without it.